# Angular 2 Ahead-of-Time compiler error

Tags: angular, deployment

I'm on `Windows 7 x64`, trying to follow instructions for [Ahead-of-Time compilation](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular/compiler-cli) of my Angular 2 application. The app compiles and runs fine with Just-in-Time compilation.

I've NPM installed `@angular/compiler-cli@0.6.0` `typescript@2.0.2` `@angular/platform-server@2.0.0-rc.6` and `@angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.6`

I get the following error when running `ngc`:

```
C:\websites\learn\angular2>"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p dev
can't resolve module @angular/core/src/di/opaque_token from C:\...\dev\index.ts
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at ReflectorHost.findDeclaration (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\reflector_host.js:171:59)
    at StaticReflector.initializeConversionMap (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:150:38)
    at new StaticReflector (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:42:14)
    at Function.CodeGenerator.create (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:142:31)
    at codegen (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:7:36)
    at Object.main (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:30:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:14:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
Compilation failed
```

Here is my folder structure (`tsconfig.json` is in `angular2` at the top-level):
[image]

At first glance, the error seems [similar to this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9663), but a closer look shows that mine ("*undefined is not a function*") is different. Any ideas?

Comment: This might also be related https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10792

Comment: Hey @GünterZöchbauer.  I took a look at that issue before posting. In that case, `ngc` is actually able to run. It just doesn't produce the expected files; it outputs `.js`, `.js.map` and `.json` files instead of `.ngfactory.ts`. In my case, nothing is output as `ngc` crashes

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with the version of node I had installed.

```
$ node --version
v0.12.7

$ npm --version
3.7.5
```

After I downloaded and installed the latest 64-bit `.msi` installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/:

```
$ node --version
v4.5.0

$ npm --version
2.15.9
```

The error no longer occurs

Comment: I'm using node v6.2.2 and npm v3.9.5 and I am still getting this error

Comment: @brando I am also getting the same error. Were you able to resolve?